# Expectation of product of three or more dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, linear-transformations

Given three random variables $X,Y,Z$, what is the formula of expectation of the product of three random variables? $$\mathbb{E}[XYZ]=?$$ 
Will it be less complex if we assume $X, Y$ and $Z$ as Gaussian distribution? Is there any formula of $\mathbb{E}[XYZ]$ in the form of expectation or covariance of two variables?

Comment: you need a generalized form of covariance. Mean and classical covariance are not enough

Comment: if you set $W:=(X,Y,Z)$ then the formula is $$\int_{{\mathbb R}^3}xyz \mathop{}\!dF_W$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the generalized form of covariance and how can it be used to find E(XYZ)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X, Y$ be independent variables taking values $\pm 1$, each with probability $0.5$. Let $Z$ be $1$ if $X$ equals $Y$ and $-1$ otherwise. Then all expected values and all pair-wise covariances are zero, but $XYZ$ is **always** $1$.

Comment: X, Y and Z are dependent variables. They can not be assumed as independent in my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @MonikaShah Not sure if we are on the same page. My $X, Y, Z$ is not an independent set of RV, otherwise, the mean would be $E(XYZ) = E(X) E(Y) E(Z) = 0$. But means and pairwise covariances are zero. That's what I'm trying to tell you: there cannot be any formula based on only pairwise interactions. You can also easily modify my example to only use Gaussian distribution; $E(XYZ)$ is not determined by means and covariances.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what you are trying to say. Could you provide me some reference where there is detail about this topic? Thank you.

Comment: Isserlis' theorem says the expectation of product of multiple RV can be determined by expectation of product of two RV. But it assumes the individual means to be zero.

Comment: Isserlis' theorem indeed says so, but the assumption there is that $(X,Y,Z)$ come from a joint multivariate normal distribution (which is much stronger than that each variable itself has normal distribution). In that case, the answer is this theorem, yeah. As you see, it cannot be generalized for any distributions. Maybe consider a new, softer question, with more background and details.